# Using replace and regex to remove characters from this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove the brackets and 'url' from a string similar to this:

url('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

So it would just leave 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'

The furthest I have got to getting this working is

```
var myvar = url('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
myvar = myvar.replace(/[url()]/g, '');
```

But obviously this would mean that any 'u', 'r', or 'l' would be removed from the actual domain.

I guess the answer would be to only remove the first instance of each of the characters.

Comment: `var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";` wrap in quotes to make it string. Open browser console to check errors

Answer (score 3):

Use capturing group.

```js
var string = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
var url =   string.replace(/\burl\('([^()]*)'\)/g, "$1")
document.write(url)
```

Comment: The real problem is with the `myvar`. It is not _string_ that contains url, it is something returned by function `url()`

Comment: `var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace(/[url()]/g, '');` Execute in `console`

Comment: @Tushar ya, it seems like a typo.

Comment: @Tushar _I am trying to remove the brackets and 'url' from a string similar to this:_ Its a string only

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Can you please read the previous comments here. `var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace(/[url()]/g, '');` Execute in `console`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-regex replace since you are remove just once:

```js
var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace("url('", '').replace("')", "");
document.write(myvar);
```

For the regex-iacs:

```js
var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace(/^url\('|'\)$/g, '');
document.write(myvar + "<br/>");

 // or even
var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace(/\bUrl\('|'\)/ig, '');
document.write(myvar);
```

Comment: The real problem is with the `myvar`. It is not _string_ that contains url, it is something returned by function `url()`

Comment: @Tushar: I believe that is an OP's typo, and it is a string. Otherwise, the original code does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using string as mentioned by Tushar.

```
var myvar = "url('http://www.stackoverflow.com')";
myvar = myvar.replace(/[url()]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string always has that format, you don't need to replace, you can just remove the characters from the start and end:

```
myvar = myvar.substr(5, myvar.length - 8);
```